# MySQL join tables with subquery

Tags: mysql, loops, date, while-loop, stack

I have this crazy query below. I want to organize them but don't know how.
Can someone help me run this query? I want to join the 5 sub-query tables below and at the end, the result would be a table displaying line item_id with last5days, last10days, last30days, last60days, last90days.
Thanks a bunch!

```
Select q1.line_item_id, 
       q1.domains as 'last5days', 
       q2.domains as 'last10days', 
       q3.domains as 'last30days', 
       q4.dpmains as 'last60days', 
       q5.domains as 'last90days'
From q1
Join q2 on q1.line_item_id = q2.line_item_id
Join q3 on q1.line_item_id = q3.line_item_id
Join q4 on q1.line_item_id = q4.line_item_id
Join q4 on q1.line_item_id = q5.line_item_id


select q1.line_item_id, count(*) domains
from (
      select distinct line_item_id, domain
      from rpt_domain_by_campaign
      where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
      and now()
      ) q1
group by q1.line_item_id


select q1.line_item_id, count(*) domains
from (
      select distinct line_item_id, domain
      from rpt_domain_by_campaign
      where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
      and now()
      ) q2
group by q1.line_item_id


select q1.line_item_id, count(*) domains
from (
      select distinct line_item_id, domain
      from rpt_domain_by_campaign
      where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
      and now()
      ) q3
group by q1.line_item_id


select q1.line_item_id, count(*) domains
from (
      select distinct line_item_id, domain
      from rpt_domain_by_campaign
      where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
      and now()
      ) q4
group by q1.line_item_id


select q1.line_item_id, count(*) domains
from (
      select distinct line_item_id, domain
      from rpt_domain_by_campaign
      where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
      and now()
      ) q5
group by q1.line_item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use sum and case make more easy:

`select line_item_id, 
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 5 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last5days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 10 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last10days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 30 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last30days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 60 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last60days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 90 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last90days'
from rpt_domain_by_campaign
Group by line_item_id`

Comment: If the some event_date of records are in future you need to add another condition in 
WHEN like WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) > 0 AND DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 5 then
OR It will miscount....

Comment: select ...
from 
(
select line_item_id, min(event_date) event_date
from 
rpt_domain_by_campaign
where event_date >= curdate()
group by line_item_id, domain
) a
Group by line_item_id

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `count(distinct...)` to avoid the extra layer of nesting in each of your sub-queries.

I also recommend switching the order of sub-queries and using outer joins because not every line item with rows in the past 90 days will also have rows in the past 60 days, etc.

Try something like this:

```
Select q1.line_item_id, 
       q1.domains as last90days, 
       coalesce(q2.domains,0) as last60days, 
       coalesce(q3.domains,0) as last30days, 
       coalesce(q4.domains,0) as last10days, 
       coalesce(q5.domains,0) as last5days
from 
(
  select line_item_id, count(distinct domain) as domains
  from rpt_domain_by_campaign
  where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
  and now()
  group by line_item_id
) q1 
left outer join
(
  select line_item_id, count(distinct domain) as domains
  from rpt_domain_by_campaign
  where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
  and now()
  group by line_item_id
) q2 on q1.line_item_id = q2.line_item_id
left outer join
(
  select line_item_id, count(distinct domain) as domains
  from rpt_domain_by_campaign
  where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
  and now()
  group by line_item_id
) q3 on q1.line_item_id = q3.line_item_id
left outer join
(
  select line_item_id, count(distinct domain) as domains
  from rpt_domain_by_campaign
  where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
  and now()
  group by line_item_id
) q4 on q1.line_item_id = q4.line_item_id
left outer join
(
  select line_item_id, count(distinct domain) as domains
  from rpt_domain_by_campaign
  where event_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
  and now()
  group by line_item_id
) q5 on q1.line_item_id = q5.line_item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use group by max date

`select line_item_id, 
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 5 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last5days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 10 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last10days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 30 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last30days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 60 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last60days',
    Sum( CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(curdate(), event_date) <= 90 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'last90days'
from 
(
select line_item_id, max(event_date) event_date
from 
rpt_domain_by_campaign
where event_date < curdate()
group by line_item_id, domain
) a
Group by line_item_id`